# MigLayout: Put two JLabel on the same line separated by JTextField

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel, jtextfield, miglayout

How do I set two JLabels separated by a JTextField in the same line? I am using MigLayout. I have the following code

```html
  JPanel helper = new JPanel( new MigLayout() );
  helper.add( new JLabel( "Threshold:" ), "" );
  threshold = new JTextField();
  Icon thresholdIcon = UIManager.getIcon( "OptionPane.questionIcon" );
  JLabel thresholdIconLabel = new JLabel( thresholdIcon );
  thresholdIconLabel.setToolTipText( "Threshold for template matching" );
  helper.add( threshold, "wrap, width 100:20" );
  helper.add( thresholdIconLabel, "wrap, width 100:20" );
```

The output that I get looks like the following.

[image]

I want the icon on the same line as Threshold and the text field. How should I adjust it? 
Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using row/column constraints and using "cell" arguments when placing the Components? I've had a lot of success with that method.

```
    JPanel helper = new JPanel(
            new MigLayout(
                    "", 
                    "5[grow,fill]10[grow,fill,20:100]10[grow,fill,20:100]5",
                    "5[fill,grow]5"));
    helper.add( new JLabel( "Threshold:" ), "cell 0 0" );
    threshold = new JTextField();                  // Assuming this was declared earlier
    Icon thresholdIcon = UIManager.getIcon( "OptionPane.questionIcon" );
    JLabel thresholdIconLabel = new JLabel( thresholdIcon );
    thresholdIconLabel.setToolTipText( "Threshold for template matching" );
    helper.add( threshold, "cell 1 0" );
    helper.add( thresholdIconLabel, "cell 2 0" );
```

Make a point of reading both the [MigLayout Whitepaper](http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html) and [MigLayout Quick Start Guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf), as they do a really good job of explaining everything at your disposal.

Sidenotes:

1. The reason it's not showing up in one line is because you're telling MigLayout it's okay to `wrap` the Components to fit in the space you're giving it, including making new lines to accommodate. You could also try increasing the size of the window.
2. The size `100:20` translates to 100px minimum size, but a 20px preferred size, and I don't know how MigLayout would handle that. I changed it in my code.

(Disclaimer: code is untested and may be a little rough)